# Clarification on converting char to string using string::at

Tags: c++, string, backslash

So I want to convert every instance of a \ into \\ for using in a function that creates directories.

```
string stripPath(string path)
{       
    string newpath;  
    for (int i = 0; i <= path.length() ;i++)
    {
        if(path.at(i) == '\\')
        {
            string someString( path.at(i) );
            newpath.append(path.at(i));
            newpath.append(path.at(i));
        }
    else
    newpath.append(path.at(i));
    }
    return newpath;
}
```

newpath.append needs a string so I'm trying to create a string out of path.at(i). I get an error on Visual Studio that says no instance of constructor matches the argument list. I imported string already.

Here is the documentation for string:at. I'm quite confused because I think I'm doing it right?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/

Comment: You understand that `'\\'` as a literal is just a single backslash in a string right?  The only reason you need to use it is that a single backslash is an escape character that means the next character is special.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: And if you need to send an escaped string to a separate program?

Comment: @MooingDuck Sure, there are plenty of reasons to do it, but just pointing out that if it's just a string to pass to `mkdir()`, `CreateDirectory()`, etc. then it isn't necessary.

Comment: I'm using SHCreateDirectoryEx which needs two backslashes. I tested it out and it only creates a directory if there are two backslashes.

Comment: @user2619824: er, it doesn't need two backslashes.  What does require two backslashes is string literals.  You didn't happen to be testing `SHCreateDirectoryEx` with string literals did you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error concerns the call to [append](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/append/), it should be:

```
newpath.append(1, path.at(i));
```

Comment: This works also... I'm confused though, what does the 1 indicate? And how did you know that that was the right format looking at the documentation. I couldn't have figured that out from looking at the documentation, so clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: Please look at the link I've provided. "1" means that the character specified in the second parameter is to be appended once. There is no overload of append that accepts only one 'char' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` doesn't have any constructor which uses a `char&` as an argument. The call should be:

```
string someString( 1,  path.at(i) );
```

Comment: char& means that it is an address of a char, right? Is that different from &char?

Comment: @user2619824 No, char& means a reference to a char, references are like pointers but they use normal variables syntax, just as an alias of a variable; which is different to & operator, which retrieves the address of a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Appending single characters is idiomatically done with the `+=` operator:

```
newpath += path.at(i);
```